How to covert an input into a capitalized form in python?
Example
.lower() used in inputs to create the input into lower case is there the same kind of function for capitalized form?
I thought it would be something like  .capitalize() but I turned out wrong. So I turned here hoping for some answer of if it exists or not.

its string.upper()

There is a method upper().
a = "abc" print(a.upper()) # ABC

Start with the Python docs on str.lower() and read a little bit up and down until you find what you're looking for. There's really no need to ask what can easily be looked up in the docs or found with a search engine. Also, please don't spam tags. This is not related to NLP, it's just a basic Python question.

The string method str.upper will return a copy of the string with all characters uppercased:
s = 'tEsT'  # Initialize a string variable
print(s.upper())  # Prints 'TEST'

Conversely str.lower will return a copy of the string with all characters lowercased:
print(s.lower())  # Prints 'test'

While as you observed str.capitalize will return a copy of the string with only the first character uppercased while making the rest lowercased:
print(s.capitalize())  # Prints 'Test'


Done, marked as duplicate. I just saw someone else trying to edit this answer without any links.

.upper() will turn your string into its uppercase form.
a = 'abc'
print(a.upper())

Returns ABC

Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, you can use code blocks to make your formatting clearer (and sometimes add syntax highlighting!).

Actually, it won't "convert" the string as they are immutable in Python. It will return a copy of a turned to uppercase. Doing print(a) will still print the original string.
